# Pygame returns an error when you click a sprite with another sprite that isn't listed

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, pygame, pygame-surface

I'm just making a title screen for a future project, and when I run it the "PLAY" and "QUIT" buttons work fine enough but when you click the surrounding background or the title image, the game freezes up and returns the error, "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'sprites'" I tried adding a blank audio file seperate from the "if play == 0:" in case it was just confused when it had nothing to do, but the problem stayed.

```
import pygame
 
# Define some colors
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
YELLOW = (255,255,0)
score = 0
play = 0

class Sprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,filename):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load(filename).convert()
        self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
class Player(Sprite):
    def update(self):
        """ Method called when updating a sprite. """
 
        # Get the current mouse position. This returns the position
        # as a list of two numbers.
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
 
        # Now see how the mouse position is different from the current
        # player position. (How far did we move?)
        diff_x = self.rect.x - pos[0]
        diff_y = self.rect.y - pos[1]
 
        # Loop through each block that we are carrying and adjust
        # it by the amount we moved.
 
        # Now wet the player object to the mouse location
        self.rect.x = pos[0]
        self.rect.y = pos[1]
 
class Block(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, color, width, height):

        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
        super().__init__()
 
        # Create an image of the block, and fill it with a color.
        # This could also be an image loaded from the disk.
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(color)
 
        # Fetch the rectangle object that has the dimensions of the image
        # image.
        # Update the position of this object by setting the values
        # of rect.x and rect.y
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

# Initialize Pygame
pygame.init()
 
# Set the height and width of the screen
screen_width = 750
screen_height = 500
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([screen_width, screen_height])

pygame.display.set_caption("LARP")
 
# This is a list of 'sprites.' Each block in the program is
# added to this list. The list is managed by a class called 'Group.'
block_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
quit_block = pygame.sprite.Group()
start_block = pygame.sprite.Group()

title_image = pygame.image.load("title.png").convert_alpha()
quit_image = pygame.image.load("quit.png").convert_alpha()
logo_image = pygame.image.load("logo.png").convert_alpha()
player_image = pygame.image.load("player.png").convert_alpha()
background_image = pygame.image.load("title_screen.png").convert_alpha()
bomp = pygame.mixer.Sound("bump.wav")
# This is a list of every sprite.
# All blocks and the player block as well.
player_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
 
#for i in range(50):
     #This represents a block
    #block = Block(BLACK, 20, 15)
 
     #Set a random location for the block
    #block.rect.x = random.randrange(screen_width)
    #block.rect.y = random.randrange(screen_height)
 
     #Add the block to the list of objects
    #block_list.add(block)
    #all_sprites_list.add(block)


title = Sprite("title.png")
title.rect.x = 340
title.rect.y = 230
all_sprites_list.add(title)
start_block.add(title)
quitg = Sprite("quit.png")
quitg.rect.x = 340
quitg.rect.y = 350
all_sprites_list.add(quitg)
quit_block.add(quitg)
logo = Sprite("logo.png")
logo.rect.y = 90
logo.rect.x = 310
all_sprites_list.add(logo)
block_list.add(logo)
player = Player("player.png")
player_list.add(player)
all_sprites_list.add(player)


 
# Loop until the user clicks the close button.
done = False
 
# Used to manage how fast the screen updates
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
 
# Hide the mouse cursor
pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
 
# -------- Main Program Loop -----------
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
 
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            # When the mouse button is pressed, see if we are in contact with
            # other sprites:
            if play == 0:         
                start_block = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, start_block, True)
                if len(start_block) >= 1:
                    play += 1    

                quit_block = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, quit_block, True)
                if len(quit_block) >= 1:
                    done = True
            #print(score)
            #blocks_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, block_list, True)
            #if len(blocks_hit_list) >= 1:
                #score +=1


            # Set the list of blocks we are in contact with as the list of
            # blocks being carried.
            #player.carry_block_list = blocks_hit_list
 
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            # When we let up on the mouse, set the list of blocks we are
            # carrying as empty.
            player.carry_block_list = []

 
    all_sprites_list.update()
    
 
    # Clear the screen
    screen.fill(WHITE)
 
    # Draw all the spites
    if play == 0:
        screen.blit(background_image, [0,0])
        all_sprites_list.draw(screen)
    screen.blit(player_image, [player.rect.x, player.rect.y])
 
    # Limit to 60 frames per second
    clock.tick(60)
 
    # Go ahead and update the screen with what we've drawn.
    pygame.display.flip()
 
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

`start_block` and `quit_block` are `pygame.sprite.Group()`. However, [`pygame.sprite.spritecollide()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollide). Therefore an instruction like:

> ```py
> start_block = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, start_block, True)
> ```

makes no sense because the group `start_block` is overwritten with the list `start_block`

Change the name of the variable the gets the return value. e.g.:

```py
start_block_hit = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, start_block, False)
```

Note, you don't need to store the return values at all.  The *doKill* argument must be `False`, otherwise your button will be destroyed when you click it:

```py
if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, start_block, False):
    play += 1    

if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, quit_block, False):
    done = True
```